# WAMP localhost refused to connect

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I recently re-installed WAMP (Windows 11) following issues upgrading WAMP versions.

When I try to connect to my local website (http://localhost/mysite), I see in browser: "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.". If I specify the port in the URL (http://localhost:8080/mysite), it will connect, but only for projects that are basic HTML. I never had to include the port previously.

What I've tried so far:

1. Changed Apache port to 8080.
2. Test port 8080 via WAMP - reports it is used by WAMP's Apache server.
3. Verified that I can access localhost:8080 in my browser (I can, and see my projects listed).
4. Verifed that all services are running in WAMP. They are - WAMP icon is green.
5. Check Apache error logs - no errors.
6. Check state of services - no errors. All marked as 'started'.
7. I am able to access phpmyadmin and see my databases which I copied from the previous installation.
8. Cleared Hosts file of everything except

   127.0.0.1 localhost
   ::1 localhost
9. Checked correct port (8080) is listening in httpd.conf
10. Disabled Windows Defender Firewall
11. Flushed DNS

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

OK so when I reset my WAMP port from 8080 to 80 in the WAMP settings, it worked again.

I now understand that browsers listen on port 80 by default. If you specify apache to run on a different port, you therefore need to manually tell your browser in the URL to use a different port, hence localhost:8080 required in the URL. But it seems that for whatever reason this does not play nice with local WordPress installs etc.